# How to extract the experience from resume using python?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, nltk

I have extracted mail id, phone number- By using regular expressions
I have extracted the name by using Core NLP server
I had extracted skills by giving in a set and comparing the words.
But I didn't have any idea how to extract the years of experience using python -
Can anyone please give an idea regarding it?
Examples:

> 2 years of experience
>
> Two years of experience
>
> 2010-2014

Like this, there are so many possibilities.

Comment: What you mean by so many possibilities, finally you need to find a logic behind your expected pattern for example by it's surrounding strings or if the shapes of intended pattern are limited you can use those structures on multiple ways like regex.

Comment: @Kasramvd the 3 listed ways are all alternative methods of listing experience, there may not be "many" ways, but there is not really a pattern amongst all, mostly just the first two

Comment: Ok but the only way is to use regular expression or we can use any other logic

Comment: @cricket_007 Yeah, it seems so.

Comment: Maybe there are another ways without using regular expression, for example splitting your text and processing the smaller parts or maybe you could ease the problem with regular expression and use another functions in order to get the real result. The point is that you need to survey the text you are dealing with and specify the whole aspects of your problem. The problem is that at the moment your information is defective and I can't help anymore. You better to update your question with more info if you want to get a proper answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can take a couple of approaches. If there are lots of possibilities, as you say, you can treat this as a machine learning problem and use approach 1. Otherwise 1, if the possibilities are limited (say, around 5), you can use the second approach.

**Approach 1:**

Consider it a machine learning problem. Classify each sentence in the text as 0 or 1 depending on if it contains the year of experience. This can be done by training some data manually. Against each training example, you will assign a label. For example:

Job Experience: 3 years   (Label 1)

Studying for two years    (Label 0)

Working hard for years    (Label 0)

Two years of experience   (Label 1)

Experience: 2010-2014     (Label 1)

Once you have a lot of examples, you can use `skicit-learn` or a similar package to train a model.

**Approach 2:**

1- Search for years. Either, it could be the exact word (`year` or `years`), or a four digit number (e.g, 2014).

2- If `1` passes, search for the word experience (or something like that) in a close proximity.

If both `1` and `2` pass, then you have years of experience. Then, depending on what you want, you can further extract.

Comment: Yes, the resume *could* show the word experience around a date range, but I think the question is asking for a way to not require a certain format of input data. In any case, listing the date range at a certain job is definitely a valid way to show years of experience

Comment: Well, as I demonstrated in my answer, there is a pattern in all the possibilities. Anyway, the other approach is to use machine learning, which I have added in my answer.

Comment: Can you please give the explanation regarding approach 1 as I am new to machine learning

Comment: Expanded my answer.

Comment: using a trained classifier seems like real overkill here.